# How to just get last letter of string instead of whole string

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I currently have a function that searches an array of strings and accepts a char argument and returns an int signalling the number of occurrences ending with the character given, and I need to modify it so it only counts the occurrences that end in that specific character.

For example:

If I had Luke and Jen and i was looking for 'e' then the output would be one as luke is the only one that ends in 'e'

This is my current code.

```
public int countFirstNameOccurrences(char c) {
        return Reg.stream()            // get Stream<Name>
                .map(Name::getFirstName) // convert Stream<Name> to Stream<String> using Name's firstName
                .mapToInt(s -> s.length() - s.replace(String.valueOf(c), "").length()) // calculate every occurrence c in each firstName and get an IntStream
                .sum();                  // sum all the values
    }
```

Comment: why are using a stream? seems a bit overkill versus a simple for loop that looks ahead by one for a white space char and sees if the char behind the white space is your target char which then increments a counter.. or if the string can be indexed like an array just split the sentence by white space and then check the last index of each array

Comment: `return Reg.stream().map(Name::getFirstName).filter(s -> s.charAt(s.length() -1) == c).count()` ? You'd need to check the empty/null string case as well if needed.

Comment: @mad.meesh This is one of many methods that do lots of different things

Comment: @LukeHetherington true but i was just curious

Comment: @AlexisC. That code works but only with the return type being long, i need the return type to be int.

Comment: Then cast the result to int ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either this:

```
public int countFirstNameOccurrences(char c) {
        String character = String.valueOf(c); // character represented as a String
        return Reg.stream()  // Stream<Name>
                  .map(Name::getFirstName) // Stream<String>
                  .mapToInt(n -> n.endsWith(character)? 1 : 0) // IntStream
                  .sum(); // int
}
```

or as Alexis has suggested but you'd need to cast to `int` as `count` returns a `long` type.

```
public int countFirstNameOccurrences(char c) {
        return (int)Reg.stream() //Stream<Name>
                       .map(Name::getFirstName) // Stream<String>
                       .filter(n -> n.charAt(n.length() -1) == c) // Stream<String>
                       .count(); // long
}
```

Comment: `n -> n.charAt(n.length() -1) == c` doesn’t handle empty strings, so it might be preferable to stay with `.filter(n -> n.endsWith(character))`

Comment: @Holger or `.filter(n -> n.length() >= 1).filter(n -> n.charAt(n.length() -1) == c)` . but i'd thought i'd leave it to OP to perform futher validations.

Comment: Right, or `.filter(n -> !n.isEmpty() && n.charAt(n.length() -1) == c)`. Just noted that there is a semantic difference between the two variants.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have an accepted answer, but some people unfortunately are forced to use Java versions lower than 8, so here's an alternative without using a stream:

```
public static int count(char c) {
    int count = 0;
    for (String name : names) {
        if (name.charAt(name.length() - 1) == c) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Simple example [here](https://ideone.com/E7xK3k).